# Which characters to escape when using RegExp object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the regex `^\(\d+\)` which is designed to match parentheses containing digits and which does what is expected.

I want to extend this to match digits in parentheses followed by a space followed by a string which comes from a variable. I know that I can crate a `RegExp` object to do this but am having trouble understanding which characters to escape to get this to work. Is anybody able to explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do not use `RegEx`, you can use a **literal notation**:

`/^\(\d+\)/`

But when you are using the RegEx **constructor**, you need to double escape these symbols:

`var re = new RegExp("^\\(\\d+\\)");`

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> There are 2 ways to create a RegExp object: a literal notation and a
>   constructor. To indicate strings, the parameters to the literal
>   notation do not use quotation marks while the parameters to the
>   constructor function do use quotation marks.
>
> ...
>   Use literal notation when the regular expression will remain constant.
>
> ...
>   Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will > be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from
>   another source, such as user input.

Now, in case you have a variable, it is a good idea to stick to the constructor method.

```
var re = new RegExp('^\\(\\d+\\) ' + variable);
```

Escaping the slash is obligatory as it is itself is an escaping symbol.

Comment: My wording was a bit ambiguous. I don't to match `(34 variable)` but `(34) variable`. Therefore I used `var re = new RegExp('^\\(\\d+\\) ' + variable);`. Thanks for your help in solving this :)

Comment: @Michael: Good, I updated the answer and also added more on the subject.