# Regex created with constructor not working with Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, safari

It is documented that one can create regex expressions using 2 methods:

1.simple expression

```
   /ab+c/i;
```

2.using a constructor

```
  new RegExp(/ab+c/, 'i');
  new RegExp('ab+c', 'i');
```

I have used the version RegExp(/ab+c/, 'i') which passed in Chrome, Mozilla but not in Safari, returning an error:

```
cannot supply flags when constructing one regexp from another
```

I have switched to the first method and it works now but there are 2 things that are not clear for me:

1. what does '/' character stand for in an expression like that. I've seen it added by default in online regex test sites
2. why safari failed to work with the version that i used

Comment: Currently, Safari does not accept a regex literal in a RegExp constructor. `/.../` are regex delimiters (delimiting action/pattern/modifiers).

Comment: Why do you even want to pass a regex literal to the RegExp() constructor? It's redundant.

Comment: Thank you. I did use the version of the constructor and the quotes as a delimiter, however because i have a pretty complicated regex that version failed in chrome and mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex constructor notation (`new RegExp(...)`) is mainly used when you need to pass a variable to your pattern. If the pattern is "hard-coded", use  a regex literal *straight away*: `var reg = /ab+c/i`. See [more on when to use which notation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110479/which-characters-to-escape-when-using-regexp-object-in-javascript/29110546#29110546).

Safari currently does not accept a regex literal as the first argument to the `RegExp` constructor, nor do some other browsers. Thus, it is safer to pass a regular string pattern as the first argument.

As for the `/.../`, these are regex delimiters that delimit *action*/*pattern*/*modifiers*. In JS, the *action* part is not used, and the modifiers are limited to `i` (case-insensitive), `g` (global matching) and `m` (multiline mode to redefine the `^` and `$` behavior so that they could match the start/end of a line instead of the start/end of a string).