# JS: Regular expression SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that there are similar questions, but can't get it over there.
I have such regex:

```
const pattern = new RegExp(
      `(?<=(.)?)\\b.{0,${truncateLength}}${searchExpression}.{0,${truncateLength}}\\b(?=(.)?)`,
      'i'
    );
```

Same for:

```
   const pattern = new RegExp(
      '(?<=(.)?)\\b.{0,' +
        truncateLength +
        '}' +
        searchExpression +
        '.{0,' +
        truncateLength +
        '}\\b(?=(.)?)',
      'i'
    );
```

Unfortunately, it's not working is safari. How can it be replaced to support all browsers? Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919802/regex-created-with-constructor-not-working-with-safari) help ?

Comment: Don't use template literals, also look to  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @Anonymous How can it be applied to the current one?

Comment: @MohamedAbdallah I need to pass values to the regex, so it won't help

Comment: @lecham use the normal way `"something" + variable + "something"`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably not with regex, but with your template literals. Some older browsers will not support template literals. I would advise using babel to transpile your code. You can keep your template literals, but the final version will have been modified to use older string concatenation, which will work on older browsers. You should look [here](https://babeljs.io/setup) for how to get started.

Comment: Even if I use it in this way:
`
const pattern = new RegExp(
      '(?<=(.)?)\\b.{0,' +
        truncateLength +
        '}' +
        searchExpression +
        '.{0,' +
        truncateLength +
        '}\\b(?=(.)?)',
      'i'
    );
`

I am getting SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

Comment: I would then advise plugging your regex into a website like this: https://regex101.com to see what exactly is wrong with your regex. I know that there are different flavors of regex, so that might be problem.

Comment: found a solution by replacing <= with :